# Angular2 ng-bootstrap - no provider error

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to integrate ng bootstrap UI into my Angular 2 project. 
After following the simple instructions found here: 
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started i get the following error when using any ngb bootstrap tag:

> **Error: No provider for NgbAlertConfig!**

### app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StocksComponent } from './stocks/stocks.component';

import { HighlightDirective } from './highlight.directive';
import { StockService } from './stock.service';
import { DateFormatterPipe } from './date-formatter.pipe'

import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component'

import { CurrencyService } from './currency.service';
import { BondsDirective } from './bonds.directive';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    StocksComponent,
    HighlightDirective,
    DateFormatterPipe,
    DashboardComponent,
    BondsDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    NgbModule
  ],
  providers: [StockService, CurrencyService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

### app.component.html

```
    <ngb-alert>
        Random Message
    </ngb-alert>
```

### angular-cli.json

```
    {
      "project": {
        "version": "1.0.0-beta.17",
        "name": "my-prog-cli"
      },
      "apps": [
        {
          "root": "src",
          "outDir": "dist",
          "assets": "assets",
          "index": "index.html",
          "main": "main.ts",
          "test": "test.ts",
          "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
          "prefix": "app",
          "mobile": false,
          "styles": [
            "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
            "styles.css"
          ],
          "scripts": [
              "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
          ],
          "environments": {
            "source": "environments/environment.ts",
            "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
            "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
          }
        }
      ],
      "addons": [],
      "packages": [],
      "e2e": {
        "protractor": {
          "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
        }
      },
      "test": {
        "karma": {
          "config": "./karma.conf.js"
        }
      },
      "defaults": {
        "styleExt": "css",
        "prefixInterfaces": false
      }
    }
```

[image: CONSOLE ERROR]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

import NgbModule in your app.module.ts like this-

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

and add it in imports section of ngmodule-

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
  imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

See if this helps.

Comment: I have imported NgbModule and added it to import.  Sorry I omitted this from original question.

Comment: Then can you please share your app.module.ts and app.component.ts?

Comment: have now added to the original question Sanket.

Comment: @PaddyUrlich You didn't call `forRoot`. That is the key ;-)

Comment: ahh..can't believe it was so obvious.  Thanks peeskillet and Sanket !!

Comment: Unfortunately I am new to SO and don't yet have a sufficient reputation.

Comment: .forRoot() saves my day. :) Thanks.

Comment: This DOES WORK! But if I try to use a Dismissable Alert, clicking on the X icon to dismiss the alert does NOT work. It simply does not do anything. There are no errors in the console either. I have this in my app.component.html: `<ngb-alert [dismissible]='true'>Testing from ROOT</ngb-alert>` I would appreciate any help in this regard. Thank you.

Comment: you must import FormsModule on app.module.tss `import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';`

Answer (score 13):

For anyone else that's getting this error for a different component, e.g `ngbDropdown` .. make sure you have the `ngbDropdown` set on the parent element.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue for me. Not easy to tell from the error message.

Comment: Could this answer be expanded, please. As it is, it is too terse to extract value from.

Comment: Meaning: you may have `ngbDropdownMenu` as an attribute in your template, but you do not have `ngbDropdown` as attribute in the parent to the `ngbDropdownMenu` element.