# ng-bootstrap style not importing

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

Setting up an accordion from [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples#config) but the style is not importing correctly. I expected to see gray boxes like this:

GOAL:

[image]

However my code looks like this:

[image]

---

app.module imports (using forRoot() because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40053440/angular2-ng-bootstrap-no-provider-error)):

```
NgbModule.forRoot()
```

HTML:

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0">
  <ngb-panel title="Simple">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      Hi!
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
  <ngb-panel>
    <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
      <span>&#9733; <b>Fancy</b> title &#9733;</span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
      lolzy
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

Comment: What version of ng-bootstrap are you using? You no longer need to use `forRoot()` with the most recent versions. Older versions may have required you to import Bootstrap CSS. The question you mention is from 2016, the installation has drastically changed since then for `ng-bootstrap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ng-bootstrap` [documentation](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap#dependencies) indicates:

> The only two dependencies are Angular and Bootstrap 4 CSS

You need to add a reference to Bootstrap 4.x.x CSS. This can either be done by adding a CDN `<link>` to your `index.html`. The following CDN is from the current Boostrap 4.x.x [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/#bootstrapcdn):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Or, if you are using @angular/cli, you can add [Global Styles](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles) to your `angular.json` `styles` array property with the relative path from `angular.json` to the `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`:

```
  "styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "src/styles.css",
  ],
```

You can also use import statements to the `node_modules` `bootstrap.min.css` in the `style.css` file.

```
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Hopefully that helps!