# ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[NgbDropdown -> NgbDropdown -> NgbDropdown]: NullInjectorError: No provider for NgbDropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angular, runtime-error, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm very new to angular as i'm leaning it right now in a intnership.
However, i would like to learn how to correctly set a dynamic dropdown in ngBootstap as i'm getting the following error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeRTP.jpg)

Here's my HTML:

parent:

```
<div class="container" id="container">
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" ngbDropdownToggle>
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div app-city-details-component *ngFor="let city of cityArray" [city]="city" ngbDropdownMenu>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Child:

```
<div class="container" id="container" ngbDropdownItem>
<button class="button" type="button" (click)="handleClick()">
    <p>{{city.name}}</p>
    <p>Latitudine: {{latitudine}}</p>
    <p>Longitudine: {{longitudine}}</p>
    <p>Timezone: {{timezone}}</p>
    <div app-show-weather-conditions [weather]="currentRealWeather"></div>
</button>
```

My app.module.ts:

[app.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCC92.jpg)

What i'm doing wrog?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No provider for NgbDropdown with Angular Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54816008/no-provider-for-ngbdropdown-with-angular-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your code inside a div with ngbDropdown and wrapping the child inside another div with ngbDropdownMenu.

```
<div class="container" id="container">

<!-- Add this -->
<div ngbDropdown> 

<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" ngbDropdownToggle>
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <!-- Change this -->
    <div ngbDropdownMenu>
   <app-city-details-component 
   *ngFor="let city of cityArray"    [city]="city"> 
    </app-city-details-component>
    </div>

 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It gives me another error: 'app-city-details-component' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-city-details-component' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-city-details-component' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. Thanks a lot for the reply however.

Comment: Try adding these in your App.module.ts `import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';` and
`schemas: [
  CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
],`

Comment: Thank you, i just needed to turn app-city-details-component into a div and it worked.